# libflashplayer.so missing in Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, adobe-flash

I have followed all the instructions in the [wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer), I made:

```
sudo apt install libflashplayer-nonfree
```

But after the installation the folder `/usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree` doesn't contain the library `libflashplayer.so`, there is only the `pubkey.asc` file. So Firefox can't see the plugin. I also have tried to find that library in other locations but it does not seem to be anywhere.

Comment: Was there an error reported when you ran `update-flashplugin-nonfree --install`?

Comment: I get the well known [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=flashplugin-nonfree;dist=unstable) mentioned in the wiki: `ERROR: wget failed to download http://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/D5C0FC14/fp.25.0.0.148.sha512.amd64.pgp.asc
`

Comment: Did you then use the manual work-around they suggest? If not, then you don't have the file because you didn't get the file

Comment: Ah ok I was thinking that command should be executed only to update the plugin, not for the installation.

Comment: I believe the command is also run _by_ the installation script, but if it had tried to run it would have encountered the same error as you saw post-install

Comment: @Checkinator the [manual update](https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer#Manual_update) doesn't help?

Comment: Yes, that manual operation solved my problem. I thought that installing the package from apt would add the `libflashplayer.so` automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `libflashplayer.so` won't be installed because of the well known [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=flashplugin-nonfree;dist=unstable) mentioned in the [wiki in the manual update section](https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer#Manual_update). It seems that the command to update Flash Player `update-flashplugin-nonfree --install` is also executed by the installation script, so the library couldn't be downloaded. The solution for this problem was that one suggested in the wiki in the same section. I had to download the `libflashplayer.so` file from the [Adobe site](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) and copy it in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the file "flash_player_npapi_linux.x86_64.tar.gz" from
   "https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/"
2. Unpack the tar.gz file.
3. Identify the location of the browser plugins directory, based on your
   Linux distribution and Firefox version:
   (e.g. `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`)
4. Copy libflashplayer.so to the appropriate browser plugins directory:
   `sudo cp libflashlayer.so <BrowserPluginsLocation>`
5. Copy the Flash Player Local Settings configurations files to the /usr
   directory: `sudo cp -r usr/* /usr`
6. Restart